# REGEXP end with "letter" that might have spaces after that letter

Tags: sql, regex, database

I have REGEXP expression that need to accept beginning of specific letter , anything in between the specific ending letter and also there might be spaces after that ending letter. (comes from database)
When I run my expression it doesn't give me the ending letter, because it has spaces in database after the name I am searching it

```
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cname, UPPER('^[&p_name_beginning](.*?)[&p_name_ending$]'));
```

Output:

```
JIE DONG has bought 2 car(s) and has spent $151200
JAMES BARREDO has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $300145
JUAN MENDIOLA has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $75610.89
JASON HADDAD has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $157000
JOSE ANDRADE has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $151046
JORDAN PENNEY has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $85201.92
JUAN RODAS has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $105000
```

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output. Is this regex being used in a SQL statement? If so, what RDBMS and function? If not, what language are you using this in?

Comment: ( *) (a space character followed by an asterisk) will match zero or more space characters. Is that what you're looking for? Also, if that '$' is meant to match the end of the string, you'll want to move it outside the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You will get better help if you specify what you are trying to do with sample before and after data, as well as showing what you have tried.  I suspect you are trying to select a row where the first and last letters of the name match parameters you have been given.  If you update the tag to show what database you are using, you will get a more targeted answer, but I here's an Oracle solution to return the 3rd record that may help if my assumption is correct. It will give you a hint at any rate.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'JIE DONG has bought 2 car(s) and has spent $151200' from dual union all
  select 'JAMES BARREDO has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $300145' from dual union all
  select 'JUAN MENDIOLA has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $75610.89' from dual union all
  select 'JASON HADDAD has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $157000' from dual union all
  select 'JOSE ANDRADE has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $151046' from dual union all
  select 'JORDAN PENNEY has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $85201.92' from dual union all
  select 'JUAN RODAS has bought 1 car(s) and has spent $105000' from dual
)
select str
from tbl
where regexp_like(str, '^j\S+ \S+a .*$', 'i');
```

The regex reads as follows:

```
^       Anchor to the start of the line
j       Match a 'j' (first letter of name)
\S+     Followed by one or more characters that are not spaces
<space> Then a space character
\S+     Followed by one or more characters that are not spaces
a       Then the ending letter of the name
<space> Followed by a space character
.*      Followed by zero or more of any characters
$       The end of the line
```

The 'i' means case-insensitive.